# Data Uri - Can I use data uri on url?

Tags: html, url, uri

For example, I can open a pdf on this link :

http://www.foo.com/test.pdf

Can I send the pdf on data uri?

Example: data:application/pdf;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA... etc

If yes then, how can I do it?

Comment: Sure. Convert your PDF to Base64, stick `data:application/pdf;base64,` in front.

Comment: In front??

I didn't get you.

Can you show me example with url?

Comment: `data:application/pdf;base64,PDF_ENCODED_AS_BASE64_GOES_HERE`